# Car door dented

Tags: suzuki, door, dent

I dented my car door while trying to turn into a tight spot. When I took the car for service they told me that the door will have to be replaced and is gonna cost big bucks. However there is no damage to the automatic window, central locking or no problem in opening and closing the door. Should I get the door replaced or just take it to a denting and painting shop to get it repaired.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everybody will have a different answer to this question, depending on

- the money-value of the vehicle
- the sentimental-value of the vehicle
- how much longer are you planning to keep it
- when the time comes to get rid of it, are you planning to sell it or
  write it off
- how much damage is there on the door

Basically, your options are:

- **new door** Probably in the $750-$1500 range just for the door, plus labour to install it and paint it. If you are planning to sell the vehicle, this is probably the option you would pick
- **door from the junkyard** If the damage is extensive enough (if something is bent), this would be my pick. The labour cost will be the same, but the cost of the actual door will be in the $50-$300 range
- **repair the existing door** You are saying the door operates properly, so I am guessing the damage is mostly cosmetic. The paint is probably scraped and the panel may be slightly bent inward. If you shop around, you may find a shop willing to do the absolute minimum to fix it (push the panel back out to it's original shape and paint the damaged section). My prefered option if the damage is mostly cosmetic
- **leave it alone** Don't fix it. If the paint isn't scratched all the way to the actual metal, it may not rust. Sure, it's probably unsightly, but it's a $0 cost.

Answer (score 4):

It is not compulsory to repair the door as long as there are no sharp edges which may cause injury to a pedestrian. The main reason most people want to repair or replace the door is for cosmetic appearance.The side door on my business van has been damaged for the last 4 yrs but still passes the mot.as it still works and the expense is not worth the difference it makes to the resale price or the extra insurance premiums charged.